# Interactive map for processing traffic data

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm making an application to process traffic data using python and postgresql. I need to create a GUI for users to select options such as dates, times, settings, etc. I've done this once before using QT Designer. This time, I need to create a map interface which allows users to select various points or segments on a map for processing. I would plot the locations of detectors, for example, and the user would select the end points of the segment they'd like to process and I would need to determine the points between as well. Potentially, I'd like to output some of the analysis to the map, but I'm mostly concerned about this base functionality as I've never done this before. I'm looking for a straightforward method with a low learning curve. I've looking into QML and creating a HTML/javascript based application, but wondering if there are other options or if one of these is the best? I would prefer not to mess with HTML/javascript too much unless it's clearly the best solution for my needs. I really appreciate any feedback.

Comment: I just did something similar to this (display an image file, and allow user to select points on it, then process selected points) using PyQt.  Have a look at QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView.

Comment: What sort of maps are you using? What is the target platform? Is this a desktop application?

Comment: I'll be using OSM map tiles. I'm targeting a Windows based desktop application.

Comment: The Qt5 [Maps and Navigation APIs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/location-maps-qml.html) have built-in support for Open Street Maps. At the moment, it looks like this requires you to use QML if you need to interact with the maps. You don't have to build your *whole* application using QML, though, since you could put the map control inside a [QQuickWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwidget.html).